# how to use pre_gets_posts to exclude one queried ID from homepage loop

Tags: wp-query, functions, loop

I want to exclude the last post of the category "prima pagina" from the loop of my home page because I've got a dedicated box for it and I don't want duplicates on the page.
I'm using a child-theme but I don't want to override the index.php so I've added this code to  my **functions.php**

```
function cdbz_modify_main_query( $query ) {
    global $post;
    $exclude = [];
    $fArgs = array( 
        'category_name' => 'prima-pagina',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'fields' => 'ids'
    );
    $featured = new WP_Query($fArgs);
    foreach($featured as $fId) { $exclude[] = $fId->ID;};
    wp_reset_query();
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) { 
      $query->set('post__not_in', $exclude); 
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cdbz_modify_main_query' );
```

It breaks the site.
There are problem with the WP_query part but I don't understand why. 
If I put the same query inside another page of the template it works fine (it returns one id).
Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues here

- You custom query should be inside your conditional statement
- Use `get_posts` which only returns the `$posts` property
- `wp_reset_query()` is used with `query_posts` which you must never ever use
- No need to the `$post` global

Your code should look something like this

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cdbz_modify_main_query' );
function cdbz_modify_main_query( $query ) 
{
    if (    !is_admin() 
         && $query->is_home() 
         && $query->is_main_query() 
    ) {
            $fArgs = array( 
                'category_name' => 'prima-pagina',
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                'fields' => 'ids'
            );
            $featured = get_posts( $fArgs );

            if ( $featured )
                $query->set( 'post__not_in', $featured ); 
    }
}
```

### EDIT

From comments, you need to know why the custom query needs to be inside your conditional statement. The reason for this is, you would only want to run the custom query when we are on the home page and only for the main query. As your code stands, you are running the custom query on every page load and for all custom queries, and even on the back end, regardless. This is unnecessary and a waste of resources.

I hope that makes sense

Comment: This works, thanks! I don't understand why I need to put the query _featured_ inside the if statement. Can you please explain?

Comment: Checked! You're right, I don't need the _featured query_ everywhere. It was a silly question :) my real problem was how to get the array of ids (only one value in this case) from the WP_Query I think I need to learn more about the use of the queries. Thanks

Comment: No question is ever silly :-). `get_posts` uses `WP_Query` but only returns the `$posts` property from the query object. Also to note, `get_posts` skips pagination, so it is faster than `WP_Query` by default. So, `get_posts` is just convenient in such situations. :-) Enjoy

Comment: Just one extra note, to acces your posts in your code in question, you should use `$featured->posts`. This is exactly what `get_posts` do.